# Hibernate Search Paging with multiple entities

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I need to implement a search over multiple entities (which works) and i need to implement pagination over that search (which doesn't work).

So what i do is:

```
        //creates the initial BooleanJunction from the first QueryBuilder
        boolJunc = allQueryBuilders.get(0).bool();

        for (QueryBuilder buildeForCurrentEntity: allQueryBuilders) {
            boolJunc.should(buildeForCurrentEntity.keyword().onFields(searchedFields).matching(searchText).createQuery());
        }
        //after all BolleanJunctions are set, creates the final lucene query
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query mainLuceneQuery = boolJunc.createQuery();
        FullTextQuery jpaQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(mainLuceneQuery, classes); //classes is array of all classes used to make those QueryBuilder's

        //set pagination parameters
        jpaQuery.setFirstResult(firstResultIndex);
        jpaQuery.setMaxResults(maxNumberOfResults);

        List<?> result = jpaQuery.list();
```

For a search term that finds 10 results:

```
    if i set my paging parameters as firstResultIndex = 0 and maxNumberOfResults = 50, then it works normally
    if its firstResultIndex = 0 and maxNumberOfResults = 5 then it dosn't return anything
    if its firstResultIndex = 4 and maxNumberOfResults = 50 then it ignores firstResultIndex and just returns all 10 results
```

Is there something i am missing? How do i make pagination work in my case?